# How to get the values repeatedly in a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question here. I have this sheet 1!

```
| Case I’d   | 252725272  |                                | Time/date | 31 Jul 2018 |
|------------|------------|--------------------------------|-----------|-------------|
|            |            |                                |           |             |
| Evaluation |            |                                |           |             |
|            | Question 1 | Yes                            | 1.00      |             |
|            |            | Explanation in question 1 here |           |             |
|            | Question 2 | No                             | 2.5       |             |
|            |            | No explanation                 |           |             |
|            | Question 3 | N/A                            | 1.5       |             |
|            |            | Explanation in question 3 here |           |             |
|            |            |                                |           |             |
| Case I’d   | 437186     |                                | Time/date | 31 Jul 2018 |
|            |            |                                |           |             |
| Evaluation |            |                                |           |             |
|            | Question 1 | Yes                            | 1.00      |             |
|            |            | Explanation in question 1 here |           |             |
|            | Question 4 | No                             | 2.5       |             |
|            |            | No explanation                 |           |             |
|            | Question 5 | N/A                            | 1.5       |             |
|            |            | Explanation in question 3 here |           |             |
```

I have this case ID, date evaluation, answer, grade and comment. In sheet two I just need to fill all the case I’d with their time. (I was able to do it)

```
Case ID          Time
252725272         31 Jul 2018
437186            31 Jul 2018
```

My question would be, in sheet 3 I need an output like this

```
| Case I’d  | Evaluation | Grade | Comment                        |     |
|-----------|------------|-------|--------------------------------|-----|
| 252725272 | Question 1 | 1.00  | Explanation in question 1 here | Yes |
| 252725272 | Question 2 | 2.5   | No explanation                 | No  |
| 252725272 | Question 3 | 1.5   | Explanation in question 3 here | N/a |
| 437186    | Question 1 | 1.00  | Explanation in question 1 here | Yes |
| 437186    | Question 4 | 2.5   | No explanation                 | No  |
| 437186    | Question 5 | 1.5   | Explanation in question 5 here | N/a |
```

I need the case id repeatedly in the column as long as there would be a question. Also, I need to get the comment for its question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please format this so we can read it properly. Maybe use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: @QHarr That table generator seems like a nice tool. Thanks for the link. A VBA macro that can generate a markdown table from a rectangular range of cells would be useful. I might try to write one today.

Comment: The table has been updated.

Comment: Even though you tagged this in a way that suggests that you want to have a solution using just Excel formulas, VBA seems like a more natural approach.

Comment: Can you tell me how? Even it is in vba. Thank you